# How to add parameters to a running process or exe by default?

Tags: command-line, parameters, arguments

### Objective:

I'm trying to use a program called `Texmod.exe` to start another program (`exe`) with certain parameters.

### Background:

Texmod is program that opens up another exe and extracts/replaces textures that are pulled up in the second program while it is running. I'm trying to start the second exe with the parameters: `-AlwaysFocus -ControllerOffset=1 -SaveDataId=2`.  Starting the second exe with shortcuts/.bat that have these parameters in a command line DOES work. However, I would like to do this in conjunction with Texmod.

### Complications:

1. I'm using Texmod v0.9 b which doesn't support starting an exe with command line parameters. Newer versions, such as the open source reboot known as uMod, does support but it doesn't replace textures as well and crashes often compared to the original version.
2. Texmod.exe must start the second exe directly. Texmod can't select a shortcut to start the exe. I've tried making Texmod start another exe/.bat that then starts the second desired exe with parameters but this causes Texmod not to function.

### Methods I have thought about but not sure if they work or even possible:

1. Somehow forcing all processes started by Texmod.exe to start with certain parameters
2. Somehow force the desired exe to always start with certain parameters regardless of start method (via Texmod, shortcuts, .bat, etc)
3. Add parameters to the process started by the desired exe after it is already running

Obviously I'm open to any ideas. Is what I'm asking even possible? Sorry if it seems unclear or I sound irrational; my knowledge on this is limited.

**Edit:** @Toby Speight I'm not sure what you mean by an example of the code I'm having trouble with as I'm just wondering if it's possible to perform the scenario I described. This is where I got the [Texmod](https://code.google.com/archive/p/texmod/downloads?page=2) program from (it's the oldest release texmod.zip - Original TexMod 0.9 beta). I've searched the internet for possible solutions but I've found very few so some of the methods I've tried are:

1. Used Texmod.exe to start a desktop shortcut with target: "directory to exe" -AlwaysFocus -ControllerOffset=1 -SaveDataId=2. The result was Texmod couldn't use the shortcut and just opened the exe without the parameters.
2. Used Texmod to start an exe named caller.exe which started the exe I desired using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773952/run-a-exe-file-with-a-parameter-by-default). In command.txt, described by the instructions, I put ""name of exe.exe" -AlwaysFocus -ControllerOffset=1 -SaveDataId=2." The result was the exe started with the parameters but Texmod failed to modify the textures because it was modifying textures pulled up by caller.exe instead.
3. Used Texmod to open a .bat file with the lines: ""name of exe.exe" -AlwaysFocus -ControllerOffset=1 -SaveDataId=2." The result was the same as attempt described in #2.

**Edit2:** I also stumbled on [this page](http://www.gamerevision.com/showthread.php?8017-Launch-textmod-target-with-arguments&s=11d3ee3c0994e1daba0fc00856a0b32f) where someone else claims they managed to achieve what sounds like the objective I desire. However, I do not know enough about code to understand it. If someone could look over this to see if it would work or see if they can modify it to fit the arguments that I desire.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Please remove 'solved' from your title and post the solution you found as a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use windows registry to force Windows run another app when specific .exe is called. Let me show an example: i'm trying to use TexMod with Remember Me.

Required setup:

- Create a copy of game .exe, place it near original with different name, eg `RememberMe_copy.exe`
- Go to windows registry location `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options`
- create new **key** named as original .exe, in my case it's `RememberMe.exe`. Registry key looks like a folder.
- In this key, create new **string value** named `Debugger` with full path to **copy** of .exe with required commandline args. For example: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Remember Me\Binaries\Win32\RememberMe_copy.exe" -ReadPoolSizeFromIni`. Note the path to .exe is quoted, commandline arguments are not. String value has type `REG_SZ`.

Now when you try to run anything called `RememberMe.exe`, Windows will instead run the `RememberMe_copy.exe` with specified parameters (and something else but we don't care). This feature is left in Windows for debugging purposes.

**Finally**, open TexMod, select `RememberMe.exe`. It will think it's running original file, but instead Windows will silently run another file with another parameters. As there is nothing else in between, TexMod is happy.

**Why can't we use single file?** Well, Windows will run original .exe instead of original .exe, then instead of it will run original .exe... causing infinite loop.